# Permission denied to read file owned by user

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

I'm trying to *restart* (it is running) MongoDB on Ubuntu 14.04 but keep getting failures with this line in the log `error getting file /srv/mongodb/keyfile: Permission denied`

Here's directory structure

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root     4096 Jan 31 05:54 srv/
drw-------  2 mongodb mongodb  4096 Jan 31 07:07 mongodb/
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb  876  Jan 31 07:07 keyfile
```

The user running `mongod` is "mongodb", group "mongodb" so it should be available for reading.

If I change permissions on `mongodb/` and `keyfile` to `-rw-r--r--` it becomes readable, but mongo claims it's too permissive of course

Going cookoo with this thing already. Any suggestion what's wrong here?

Answer (score 15):

I've had the same problem before, and the solution I found and was not documented had to do with the context.  If you are in Linux try:

```
ls -lahZ
```

That will display in list, all files, sizes in human readable and Z for contexts, I noticed that the keyFile must have "system_u:object_r:mongod_var_lib_t:s0" context, so it gets fixed with:

```
chcon system_u:object_r:mongod_var_lib_t:s0 mongodb-keyfile
```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: This was it! Can you please explain what the chcon cmd is adding to the keyfile permissions?

Comment: It's a SELinux issue, the context determines which files or folders have which permissions according to type, additional to the user and group permissions, more info here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/chap-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts.html

Comment: The `keyfile` was scp from primary host, and it had `-r--------. mongod mongod unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 keyfile`. I used the `chcon` method you suggested and solved the issue.

Comment: The first step i must set `mongodb-keyfile` is own of `mongod`.

Comment: I tried to SCP all files under dbpath from replica set primary in order to recover a stale secondary. I had to run `chcon -R system_u:object_r:mongod_var_lib_t:s0 /var/lib/mongo` and  also `chown -R mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongo` to get the green light on service mongod start

Comment: @jmdiego I just realised that I downvoted this one few weeks ago but this was not my intention. I cannot remove the vote anymore until you edit.  Sorry for that.

Answer (score 7):

I got the mongod service working by changing the owner of the key file to mongod

`sudo chown mongod:mongod  mongodb.key`

the mongod process owner is mongod which tries to access the file

Comment: As you can see, the original post already had the right owner and permissions, that's why the top answer was not working for you, it asumed those were already in place.

Comment: For me it was `sudo chown mongod /etc/ssl/mongo.pem` because mongodb automatically creates a new user `mongod` to run the server

Answer (score 4):

In addition to read and write permission for a directory, usually you must have an execute permission as well (more info at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Permissions). So, you have to set the following permissions:

```
chmod 700 /srv/mongodb/
chmod 600 /srv/mongodb/keyfile
```

Comment: Mongo key file does not require for you to have execution permissions it's only the context that is wrong in this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

Since none of the answers here solved my problem, and I had the same problem exactly, I'll try to post what worked for me.

My solution:

1. Stop Mongo
2. Edit `mongod.conf` and temproraily comment out the attribute `keyFile: /path/to/key`
3. Start Mongo
4. `sudo chown mongod </path/to/key>`
5. `sudo chmod 400 </path/to/key>`
6. Remove comment from `KeyFile` attribute in `mongod.conf`
7. Restart Mongo

Hope this helps

Comment: As you can see, the original post already had the right owner and permissions, that's why the top answer was not working for you, it asumed those were already in place.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/332091/214088), the comment was right, mongo needs permissions not only in the keyfile, but in the directory:

I have just moved my keyfile from my home user /home/user/keyfile to a directory where mongodb is owner: /var/lib/mongodb/keyfile. Also remember keyfile must have 400 permissions and be owner and group of mongodb: chmod 400 keyfile chwon mongodb:mongodb keyfile