# MongoDB docker error: Failed to open /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to run a docker instance and keep coming across this server.
Here is what I get after trying to setup the instance:

```
Starting instance ... done
Attaching to instance
instance   | {"t":{"$date":"2020-12-08T14:06:42.033Z"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20574,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Error during global initialization","attr":{"error":{"code":38,"codeName":"FileNotOpen","errmsg":"Failed to open /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"}}}
instance exited with code 1
```

The file permissions are:

```
$ ls -l /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mongodb mongodb 0 Dec  8 19:32 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

What else I've tried:

1. Shutting down and removing all containers and removing the build-cache
2. Removing all .sock files from /var/lib/mongodb
3. uninstalling and reinstalling docker.
4. Checking if the ports on my .conf file are unoccupied.
5. Adding user `mongodb` as owner and group to both the lib and log mongodb folders.

I am not sure anymore where this issue is coming from.
Would like to have some alternate solutions to this.

Comment: How did you fix it? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I think the permission could be wrong for the folder. Try setting the permission 777 for log and data

Comment: facing same issue.I didn't helped me

Comment: chmod 777 -R /var/log/mongodb/ Worked for me

Comment: chmod 777 -R /var/log/mongodb/ Worked for me too

Comment: i got the error like $ chmod 777 -R mongod.cfg.
chmod: changing permissions of 'mongod.cfg': Permission denied

Comment: @DarpanRajput just use sudo

Answer (score 1):

If your mongodb was working well & suddenly it stopped working, then it can possible be an error related to permission. Below commands can be used to get back mongodb into running state -

1. check the permission of /var/lib/mongodb & /var/log/mongodb & match it with the official installtion guide.
2. try to make permission as same as guided by the official site.
3. If you are unable to resolve it that way or want a quick fix, you can do the following. it will definitely resolve the issue -

> ```
> sudo chmod 777 -R /var/log/mongodb // not good from safety perspective.
>
> sudo chmod 777 -R /var/lib/mongodb // not good from safety perspective. 
>
> sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongod-*.sock
> ```

and them you can simply restart the server & check the status with below commands -

> ```
> sudo service mongod restart 
>
> sudo service mongod status 
>
>  or 
>
> sudo systemctl restart mongod 
>
> sudo systemctl status mongod
> ```

If this answer works for you, please vote it.

Answer (score 0):

I went thru a lot of posts, changed permissions, followed this one and tried it all:

[Permission denied to read file owned by user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251531/permission-denied-to-read-file-owned-by-user)

I even followed the tutorial at mongo step by step:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-with-keyfile-access-control/

And nothing worked for me.

This one:

```
sudo chown mongodb mongo.key
```

Didnt work either, but at the end, I thought of restarting the server, and after

```
sudo service mongod start
```

and it all worked.

I have no answer why this worked, but a restart on my three servers worked just perfect.

And here's my mongod.conf

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /var/lib/mongodb/mongo.key
```

Thanks.