# How to install BigBlueButton 2.7 on Ubuntu server 20.04 without IPv6 support

Tags: ipv6, ubuntu-20.04, ipv4, bigbluebutton

Is there a way to install BigBlueButton 2.7 on a system that can only work  with IPv4 ?
I've installed previous versions of BigBlueButton several times in the past. but when I tried this one, IPv6 seems to be mandatory, and i don't understand why. normally it should be optional.

I use the bbb-install.sh (that i got from here: https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bbb-install/blob/v2.7.x-release/bbb-install.sh) script on Ubuntu 20.04

This is the command i ran:

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bigbluebutton/bbb-install/v2.7.x-release/bbb-install.sh | bash -s -- -w -v focal-270 -s virtual.mydomain.net -e admin@mydomain.net -g
```

and i'm getting this output:

```
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bigbluebutton/support/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:4 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 InRelease
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/martin-uni-mainz/coturn/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:7 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:10 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 Release
Hit:11 https://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/focal-270 bigbluebutton-focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
SHELL=/bin/bash
PWD=/root
LOGNAME=root
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
MOTD_SHOWN=pam
HOME=/root
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
SSH_CONNECTION=10.10.26.115 62847 10.176.24.152 22
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
TERM=xterm-256color
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
USER=root
SHLVL=1
XDG_SESSION_ID=199
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
SSH_CLIENT=10.10.26.115 62847 22
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/0/bus
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
_=/usr/bin/env
Your server does not support IPV6
```

I can't have a public IPV6 address how can i still install ?

Comment: Not a programming question. Post server-administration questions on SuperUser, ServerFault, or similar.

Comment: How is this programming-related?

Comment: @KenWhite  &  user1686, i've been on stackoverflow for quite a while and seen a lot of  non "programming-related" questions going around with no problem, here is an exemple: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65200670/mongodb-docker-error-failed-to-open-var-log-mongodb-mongod-log . Anyways i got my answer. Cheers!

Comment: Many of those were posted before other sites were created. For instance, this question would have been fine before [sf] was created several years ago. Also, previous questions are irrelevant, as site guidelines change over time. The only thing relevant are the guidelines that are in place right now, at the time you're asking your question, and todays guidelines say your question is off-topic.

Comment: @KenWhite Alright, i got you!  i'll do that from now on. the only discomfort is that the other sites are not as active, and certain tags are even missing, for instance the `bigbluebutton` does't exist on both SuperUser and ServerFault. but anyways i guess the rules are the rules... I personnally if this is how it should be, then some tags should be moved  or at least copied to the other sites where they are (more) relevant.

Comment: Level of activity doesn't change the guidelines here, and neither does the existence of tags at other sites. The guidelines are explained in the [help], and aren't optional (or flexible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't have a public IPV6 address

Having a public IPv6 address is not required by BigBlueButton.

What's required is having the **general IPv6 support enabled in your OS.** That is, you must *not* boot with `ipv6.disable=1` and you must *not* blacklist the `ipv6` module via modprobe. All Linux distributions, including Ubuntu, have IPv6 support active by default; if this is missing that means you (or your container host) must've deliberately turned it off.

Most of BigBlueButton component services are pre-configured so that they would create listener sockets on AF_INET *and* AF_INET6, or sometimes even using the "automatic dual-stack" support where binding on INET6 also binds on IPv4. All of that is usually harmless if you do not have a global IPv6 address – the listen will still succeed, it will just be localhost-only – *unless* you've disabled AF_INET6 support OS-wide, in which case the service will get an "Unsupported address family" error and will likely fail to start.